# Emacs adding comment char when using auto-fill-wrap

Tags: auto-fill-mode

I'm pretty new to emacs, so this might be a stupid question but

I have auto word wrap enabled like so:

```
(setq-default auto-fill-function 'do-auto-fill)
```

But when I try to use it in C files, It inserts a * before the wrapped line like a comment.

```
blah blah blah over the line limit
```

to

```
blah blah blah
*over the line limit
```

Weirdly enough, pressing enter on a comment does not add the star, which is disappointing.This does not happen in viml files (only in c and java files?)

Comment: Just to rule out the simple things, I assume it's not wrapping a multiplication, nor pointer arithmetic? If that's not the case, you might want to rule out other things in your init file by starting with a commented-out init file, set `auto-fill-function`, and test wrapping. Then, if it works as you want, uncomment out half of your init file, and see if it still works properly.

Comment: Hmm, I made some significant changes (unrelated to this issue), and I don't seem to be seeing it anymore. It was probably one of the more buggy plugins I was trying to get to work, but then removed.Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to reproduce this behavior was by setting the fill prefix:

`(setq fill-prefix "*")`

and of course that is easily cleared.

I also noticed that if you turn on auto fill in a C mode buffer with `M-: (turn-on-auto-fill)` then the auto-fill-function is set by default to `c-do-auto-fill` which will wrap within comments but not in code. With your `(setq-default auto-fill-function 'do-auto-fill)` it seems you were enabling fill for code, which is probably something most people don't want.

I think the more idiomatic way to turn on auto fill mode globally would be:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'turn-on-auto-fill)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

(I like enabling things "globally" this way because most modes derive from one of those two parent modes, and I prefer to leave my fundamental mode as unadulterated as possible)

Oh, and for getting the star auto-inserted for a manual newline, [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dLine-Comments.html) is the relevant manual page. You're supposed to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd>.